# Using a push pull type solenoid to launch a ping pong

Tags: power-electronics

For are final project in physics we are launching ping pong balls at specific targets. I wanted to make something similar to an air soft gun for this project, by that I mean I want to to use air pressure to shoot off the ping pong, using the solenoid pump to push the air towards a fine pipe which then it travels through till WAMMOO! Hopefully the ping pong ball is projected forward.

What I need to know if this is possible and I'm on the right track, as I would not like to spend money on a experiment doomed for failure.

Comment: You need to show the force/energy/impulse calculations which you are assuming here. Also clarify which aspect of your question relates to electronics design, and not physics - this sounds like a pure physics question to me.

Answer (score 3):

Solenoids are ill-suited for use in pumping compressible media like a gas with a single stroke because of their relatively short stroke.  They are also very inefficient because they only perform work when the mass is moving; when the coil is energized, the plunger moves only a short distance but the coil remains energized until it is shut off.  Also, unlike rotating machines, they do not retain any momentum but must have their entire mass accelerated, on every forward and return stroke.  I would recommend using an air pump with a valve so you can build up some pressure in a chamber and then open it to fire.